# Multiple use of same Observable with Retrofit

Tags: api, retrofit, rx-java, rx-android

I have a manager that encapsulates the call to the retrofit service because I need to save the session token and object on login, then:

```
class LoginManager {

     public static Observable<Session> login(String email, String password) {
        Credential credential = new Credential(email, password);
        Observable<Session> observable = SERVICE.createSession(credential);

        observable.subscribe(new Subscriber<Session>() {
            @Override
            public void onCompleted() {

            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Throwable e) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onNext(Session session) {
                String token = session.getToken();
                saveToken(token);
                save(session.buildCustomer());
            }
        });

        return observable;
    } 
}
```

My Service looks like:

```
public interface CustomerService {

    @POST("/api/sessions/customer")
    Observable<Session> createSession(@Body Credential credential);

}
```

Is it correct to use the observable inside the manager and outside in my activity?

What problems can it have?

---- EDIT

Changed to map:

```
class LoginManager {

     public static Observable<Session> login(String email, String password) {
        Credential credential = new Credential(email, password);
        return SERVICE.createSession(credential)
        .map(session - {
            String token = session.getToken();
            saveToken(token);
            save(session.buildCustomer());
            return session;
        });
    } 

}
```

It is a good idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `observable` will start emitting whenever someone subscribes to it.

What I would suggest you to do in your manager would be to return the `observable` and just add `.doOnNext()` to it.

```
return observable.doOnNext(new Action1<Session>() {
    @Override
    public void call(final Session session) {
        String token = session.getToken();
        saveToken(token);
        save(session.buildCustomer());
    }   
});
```

`.map` is used when you want to change the `observable` type while doing an operation on it.

This way, whenever `onNext` would happen on your observable (i.e subscribe from your activity), you would have access to the `Session` there.